# How to fix "No Operation System" Error?

Tags: installation

So my CD drive is damaged, and I wanted to format my PC with a bootable USB with Ubuntu on it.

Everything was ok, I created my bootable USB but when I tried to boot from it, a massage appeared saying:

> NO OPERATION SYSTEM

What should I do?

Comment: First of all, you need to set your machine to boot from the `USB drive`. This setting can be done in `BIOS` setup screen, normally under the `Boot` settings menu in it,

Comment: It is worth checking that the root partition on your USB is set with a bootable flag, otherwise your BIOS won't run the code.

--only applies if you formatted the USB yourself. If you used USB disk creator from within Ubuntu it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried checking if your BIOS can support bootable USBs?

If yes, you have to make sure that you change the boot order of your BIOS and that USB is first. Restart your computer and by then your system will detect your bootable USB and proceeds with the installation.

You may want to do some research about changing the boot order if you're confused on how to do that.

Or you can check it from here:

http://pcsupport.about.com/od/tipstricks/ht/bootusbflash.htm

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you didn't set the machine boot sequence in the bios to boot from usb. Based on your machine, you should be able to get into your bios via f2 or esc key. Once in, set your boot sequence to be usb first and save/exit the bios. Machine should boot using the usb where you can perform the installation. Good luck.